# How does one extract and save an incoming email in a file using outlook vba? I can't seem to get the body extracted

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to extract and save an incoming email in a file using outlook vba. Can't seem to get the body extracted.  There's no problem getting the subject or from address from MailItem. I understand that there are 3 formats, so the test code below prints them all.  But, all of them are wrong. None of the content of the 3 formats, plain, RTF, or HTML match what I know to be in the body.

the actual body content is the string, "test content".

The first MsgBox prints nothing.

The second MsgBox prints ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

The third MsgBox prints the following:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version
14.02.5004.000">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Here's my test code:

```
Sub SaveMail(objMail As MailItem)
'writes the message into a file, for later processing

    Dim strID As String
    Dim subjectStr As String
    Dim bodyStr1 As String
    Dim bodyStr2 As String
    Dim bodyStr3 As String
    Dim senderEmail As String
    Dim subject As String

    strID = objMail.EntryID
    Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)

    subjectStr = objMail.subject
    senderEmail = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    subject = objMail.subject

    bodyStr1 = objMail.Body
    bodyStr2 = objMail.RTFBody
    bodyStr3 = objMail.HTMLBody

    MsgBox (bodyStr1)
    MsgBox (bodyStr2)
    MsgBox (bodyStr3)

    'method 1 which doesn't work for the body
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tso = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Charles\ps1\outlook\" & subjectStr & "-body.txt", True)
    tso.WriteLine ("Sender: " & senderEmail)
    tso.WriteLine ("Subject: " & subject)
    tso.WriteLine ("Start Body: ")
    'tso.WriteLine (objMail.Body)
    'tso.WriteLine (objMail.RTFBody)
    tso.WriteLine (objMail.HTMLBody)
    tso.WriteLine ("End Body: ")
    tso.Close

    'method 2 which doesn't work for the body
    objMail.SaveAs "C:\Users\Charles\ps1\outlook\" & subjectStr & ".txt", olTXT

    Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all of them are wrong"?  What's wrong with them?

Comment: The contents of the MailItem.Body, MailItem.RTFBody, or HTMLBody are not what I know to be in the body.

Comment: What *do* they contain?

Comment: We can't help if you don't elaborate.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the output of the 3 MsgBox's above.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "tso.WriteLine (objMail.HTMLBody)" with "tso.WriteLine (bodyStr3)" .

I can't explain why,(except that it probably forces the object type to string) but going through a variable worked for me in the following (Kludgy!) code snippet (which in my full code module was temporarily pasted into a

```
With OutMail
.Display
.To = Email
.CC = CC
.BCC = BCC"
End with
```

section.)

```
  Dim HTMLBodyFULL
  Dim objFSO As Object
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim objFile
  HTMLBodyFULL = .HTMLBody
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strFile = "C:\TempDelete\HTMLBody.txt"
  Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile, True)
  objFile.Write HTMLBodyFULL
  objFile.Close
  Set objFile = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
```

To use in your code, I believe paste your objMail in front of the .HTMLBody (and create the TempDelete folder)

I tried one or two other ways to get the full text of one particular template email, all of which failed to give the entire text. Debug.print seemed to only give 200 lines, and Msgbox gave what you have. The total HTML lines for the 24 line email template turned out to be 641!